# Find thread currently executing the Quartz Job!

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am looking for solution to get the the thread name currently executing the quartz job. In my application, quartz is configured using properties and jobs triggers are DB driven.

Here i am instantiating the quartz and starting it.

```
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(configFile);
Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
 scheduler.addGlobalJobListener(new QuartzJobListener());
 scheduler.addGlobalTriggerListener(new QuartzTriggerListener());
scheduler.start();
```

Able to get the quartz JOB and TRIGGER details as follows,

```
try{
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
List<JobExecutionContext> jobList = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
for(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext : jobList){
    // JOB Details 
    JobDetail jobDetail = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail();
    String strJobName = jobDetail.getName();
    String strDescription = jobDetail.getDescription();

    // Trigger Details
    Trigger trigger = jobExecutionContext.getTrigger();
    String strTriggerName = trigger.getName();
    String strFireInstanceId = trigger.getFireInstanceId();
    int state = scheduler.getTriggerState(trigger.getName(),trigger.getGroup());
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My question is - **How can i get the thread name which is executing the current job?**

Here is [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128155/how-can-i-find-which-quartz-job-a-thread-is-running-in-java) addressing the same issue but havent got any solution reply as of now.

Comment: Why you need the thread that executes your job? Please elalborate on 'What' are you need to do (I think that you are little too focused on 'How' you are going to do it).

Comment: Not for processing purpose, but need to capture the details in database for future reference. As my apllication generates lots of logs and checking for each job's log each time is not possible. Hence i created listener which will capture the data on the execution. I am able to get all the details such as job's/trigger's group, name, Previious fire time, next fire time etc... but not thread related information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a

```
private Thread thead;
```

variable to your Job class and in the `execute()` method, set

```
thread = Thread.currentThread();
```

Comment: `@Vache` - Many Thanks for the hint. I am using `Thread.currentThread().getName();` in the listener, not in JOB and able to get the thread name. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only about debugging and tracing use some smart logging inside your executor and do not mess with the threads (you don't want to go there).

I am not sure Quartz gives this info to you via their API. However, you can [configure Quartz to work with your thread pool](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/configuration/ConfigThreadPool.html).Then getting the executor thread info will be much easier. You can use CommonJ for this purpose.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply but i cannot change the existing configuration as the application is in production and these changes will not be accepted or will take long time to get it approved. I have to make it without or minimal changes in existing configuration. Any other suggestion?